# Generating a uniform sample from $\{\textbf{x}\in [0,1]^d : 0 \leq x_1 \leq...\leq x_d \leq1 \}$ (not a simplex)

Tags: sampling, simplex, monte-carlo

I would like to generate a uniform sample from the set:

$$ U=\{\textbf{x}\in [0,1]^d : 0 \leq x_1 \leq...\leq x_d \leq1 \}$$

Rejection sampling (sampling from the unit cube and rejecting unsorted vectors) won't work for me as I wish to deal with high dimensions.
My current approach is to generate uniform vectors from the d-dimensional unit cube and then sort the vectors.
Does my approach indeed result in a uniform sample from $U$? Are there other interesting approaches for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, your method is correct.  There are $d!$ possible rankings for the original coordinates, all equally likely.  Sorting the coordinates maps each of these $d!$ regions in the unit cube onto the desired region in a volume-preserving way.  The result is a uniform distribution over the desired region.